# Is it illegal to going to someone's bank account and do a transfer?

Tags: banking, scams

A person I've been talking to for a while asked me to go into his bank account 
and make a transfer to a US beneficiary account. It's a continental account. It showed the  date that the account was opened in 2007 as well as a picture of him.

I trusted him and I did it. Now he is asking me to do it again and this time red flags are coming up. Can someone help me? Is it illegal to go into someone's account and make a transfer for them?

Comment: Ask yourself why would he want you to do this?

Comment: Regardless of the legality, this is a Bad Idea. What possible legitimate reason could he have to ask you to make this transfer instead of doing it himself?

Comment: I always trust my gut when it comes to bread flags. Just say no!

Comment: One guess: maybe he is setting the transaction up to look fraudulent so that he can then claim "my account was hacked by a friend I trusted", sic the police on you, and get the money refunded.

Comment: Now that the bread is gone, perhaps he'll get red and water when he's busted :->)

Comment: His reason was he wasn't in a secured Wi-Fi area because he's in a hotel in London. The thing that gets me is like I said this account has been opened for years with his picture and shows multiple large transactions into his account since May. 1 transfer in September and then the transfer I did for him which was a large amount. If it's his own account can't he have anyone transfer that he wants?

Comment: Sounds like he used a fake web page to make you think you did something that he is later going to pretend was illegal, and he will try to 'blackmail' you to pay hush money to the 'police'. However it works, it doesn't matter - this is clearly a scam. Don't involve yourself with scammers. Walk away.

Comment: @tl59 Does your bank account show you a picture of yourself? No? Because mine doesn't either. This is just a scam page made to build your trust in him. No one ever asks a random person to log into their account for them - why would they? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ritz Continental is a real banking Company and I went on to their page and then logged in with his username and password. So I do believe the account is real. I'm just freaking out now because I did one transfer for him and trust me I will not do it again

Comment: A likely possibility is that the *origin* account does not belong to your "friend", but the *destination* account does, and he has somehow acquired (purchased on the Dark Web) the credentials to the origin account. When the real owner of that account discovers the loss, the resulting investigation will show that the request came from your IP address, not the scammer's.

Comment: "Ritz Continental is a real banking Company and I went on to their page and then logged in with his username and password" I hate to break it to you, but **anyone** can set up a web page like that, and the only cost is the domain name registration and the hosting, which may be less than $25. I googled Ritz Continental and the only banking page I came up with was Ritz Continental Online which seems pretty clearly to be a dummy front: no real world contact information, no way to set up new accounts. Most of the links don't work. It's a scam, don't respond to any further contacts by these people.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I don't think this is a duplicate, as the OP is not being asked to open a new account.

Comment: Shoover... what do you mean when you say the dark web. Are you saying this person stole money from somebody and I transferred that money into his account. That is the case this will be investigated and I will be arrested. Do you have any advice on what I should do now should I go to the police?

Comment: "_His reason was he wasn't in a secured Wi-Fi area because he's in a hotel in London_" But, presumably, he felt able to send _you_ the details necessary to login over that same "unsafe" connection?

Comment: Yes thats what he said and he called me on phone to give me info not though text.

Comment: @TL59 They are saying that there's a chance the account you logged into did not belong to the person you were talking to.  They could buy account information online and then get _you_ to use it to put money in an account they are willing to access.  This makes it look like it's you stealing the money.  That said, based off what Charles is saying; it seems very possible that the account is fake and they are trying to scam you in some other way for your own money.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon: If my bank tried to show me a photo of myself, it wouldn't be my bank any longer :-)  And besides, would a serious bank call itself the Ritz-anything?

Answer (score 9):

To answer your literal question: "Is it illegal to going to someone's bank account and do a transfer?" It depends. If you have a power of attorney for the person, it's probably fine. If you are doing it for a real world friend of long standing who gave you their account name and password, it's probably not illegal, or at least beneath the notice of law enforcement. It might be against the terms of service of the bank, and theoretically could results in the bank closing your friend's account, if someone brought it to the attention of the bank, and they decided to care. On the other hand, if some "online" friend gives you the account info and it turns out it's actually stolen from some unknown third party, then yes, that is illegal almost anywhere in the world, and you are the [patsy](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=patsy) who'll be left holding the bag.

In this case it looks the "bank" you named in the comments is just a dummy web page. It is clearly not a real bank. Notice there is no "real-world" contact information (phone numbers, street address for the corporate offices, etc). Most of the links don't work, including the ones for setting up a new account. There is a genuine Continental Bank, but no Ritz-Continental Bank. They are undoubtedly trying to run some sort of scam on you, but I don't know what it is. Don't respond to any further contact from them.

Why would someone trick you into making a fake transfer on a fake website? I have absolutely no way of knowing! Here are some possibilities:

1. Just for laughs. You'd be surprised how many people get a kick from jerking other people around, and they all have access to the internet.
2. To get you to go to a website that is loaded with malware that will infect your computer. They may also now have the internet address of your computer, so they can attack it remotely.
3. To set you up for a fake police/IRS/FBI scam: "You're going to jail for making that money transfer! Unless of course you send us $500 in Amazon gift cards ...". I've gotten three calls on my landline in the last year claiming to be the IRS on their way to arrest me unless I came up with the gift cards.
4. To [establish that you're gullible enough that you're worth pursuing for the "real" scam](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/microsoft/9346371/Nigerian-scam-emails-deliberately-implausible.html).
5. The scammer is still figuring out how to turn this into a working scam, and you are one of the beta testers.

You probably are never going to know what the motivation was, but there are some important lessons for you to learn from this:

1. You can meet lots of nice people on the internet, but you can also meet a lot of con artists, criminals, and liars.
2. People you know only from online contact can lie to you with impunity. As they say, "[No one on the internet knows you're a dog.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog)"
3. Anybody can set up a web site with any content they like for about $25 a year. Simply having a web-site does not establish that something is a legitimate business.
4. No-one gives away money to random people on the internet, and no-one with any sense gives their banking information to contacts they only know from the internet. If someone is offering to do either of these it's  a scam and you are the mark.
5. In the future if someone on the internet asks you to do something that makes no sense, then for pity's sake don't do it!

Comment: Omg you wasn't on Ritz-continental.com and it's a dummy account. So when I logged onto this dummy account and he has a dummy page showing all this money what did I actually transfer if it's not even real I don't get it. His dummy account show lots of money and it showed a transfer. So if it was a dummy account that means there really wasn't money in there correct? Do you think I was just going through the motions of a transfer to him to set me up to Blackmail me?

Comment: @TL59 if I gave you a business card that said I was "James Bond" would you believe it? You can have business cards printed that say anything you like, and *anybody can set up a web site that says anything they like*. Note that if you search Google for "Ritz-Continental Bank" that website will be the only banking site you find (though there are a lot of restaurants). A real bank would show up in Google hundreds of times in links to news stories and government regulatory sites. I have no idea what they have planned for you. Maybe it's just a practical joke, but they are clearly lying to you.

Comment: @TL59 my advice would be to simply ignore any future contact from them. Now if you've given them *any* of *your* banking information, then contact your bank immediately.

Comment: No I didn't give him any of my banking information. I will not have any further contact with them but I'm very upset because someone mentioned that this money was dark web which is stolen from someone's account and I transferred it into another account. Does that mean investigators will be knocking at my door. Could I be arrested for something I did that I really thought was legitimate.

Comment: @TL59 that answer about the dark web was assuming that you were on a real banking site. As far as I can tell you weren't. If you get an email next week from someone claiming to be the FBI or the IRS saying that you need to pay $500 in Amazon gift cards or you'll be thrown in jail, then you'll know what the scam is. By the way, if that happens look up the number of the FBI or IRS in the phone book and let them know.

Comment: Thank you Charles I am so lost if this is a fake bank account which I believe now. I don't get what the purpose is pretending to do a money transfer into someone else account. I am not making any sense of this. Do you think where I transferred two was a real bank account or a fake one as well? He also does not have my email address unless he could get it because I was on his account on my computer. Why would a person set up a fake web page he fake bank account and have someone do a fake money transfer puzzling.

Comment: @TL59 this comment thread is getting too long. I've added a section to my answer  on possible motivations, but these are just my guesses. I really have no way of knowing what they're up to. To my thinking, simply knowing that they're lying closes the matter.

Comment: +1 The second list, in particular, should pop-up whenever someone types "_internet friend_" or similar into a new question!

Comment: @TL59 Just because you saw a pop up that said "transfer in progress" with a little progress bar doesn't mean the computer was actually *doing anything.*  The person who controls the website can make it do whatever he likes when you click that button. It was probably just shuffling numbers around on screen, no real money. Worst case scenario, that "transfer" might've been downloading a virus onto *your computer.*  You might want to run an anti-virus scan and/or have the computer checked out by someone techy (whom you know and trust, in the real world), to be sure.